# T-SQL Insert when not in table and when max timestamp Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, max, sql-insert

I am trying to insert rows from one table to another that are not in the one I am moving them to. I also want to only move the ones that have the highest datestamp. (I want to only insert rows that are not in tb1 and have the max timestamp)

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[tb1]
SELECT *
FROM   tb2
WHERE ( dbo.tb2.STime = (SELECT Max(STime)
                         FROM   dbo.tb2) )
      AND ( EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT EMPNO
                          FROM   [db].[dbo].[tb1]) );
```

I Get this error when I execute:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 43 An aggregate may not appear in the
>   WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause
>   or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer
>   reference.

**-EDIT
RESOLVED**

```
WITH aggregateTime (maxTime) AS (
SELECT MAX(STime) AS maxTime 
FROM tb2
)
INSERT INTO db.dbo.tb1
SELECT *
FROM tb2 
INNER JOIN aggregateTime ON 1=1
WHERE tb2.STime = aggregateTime.maxTime AND EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT EMPNO FROM tb1);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Will adding qualifiers help?  `INSERT INTO db.dbo.tb1 t1a
SELECT *
FROM tb2 t2a WHERE t2a.STime = (SELECT MAX(t2b.STime) FROM dbo.tb2 t2b) AND 
                   t2a.EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT t1b.EMPNO FROM db.dbo.tb1 t1b)`

Comment: Im Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CTE with just one column that is the maxtime from tb2. Then join on the CTE and reference it when checking for if its the max or not.

```
WITH aggregateTime (maxTime) AS (
    SELECT MAX(STime) AS maxTime 
    FROM tb2
)
INSERT INTO tb1 (id, EMPNO, Street1)
SELECT id, EMPNO, Street1
FROM tb2 
INNER JOIN aggregateTime ON 1=1
WHERE tb2.STime = aggregateTime.maxTime AND EMPNO NOT IN (SELECT EMPNO FROM tb1);
```

Working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/141bf/4

Comment: For some reason the edit service call was returning a 500 error response

Comment: I'm getting an "Incorrect syntac near WHERE" error. Not sure why though

Comment: I had aggregate.maxTime instead of aggregateTime.maxTime. I fixed that can you try again?

Comment: The error still remains. I also have this erro  in front of INNER JOIN aggregateTime. "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

Comment: I updated the query and made a SQLFIddle example showing that it works

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I forgot to mention. I don't have STime in tb1. It is basically there to keep track of groups of rows. (I have an SSIS import) When inprted to tb2 the table auto adds a timestamp but I only want everything else besides the STime to be inserted into tb1. idk if this would effect it. I am messing with sqlfiddle to see if I did something wrong when transfering my data to your example

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much for your time and help! I added an Insert into above the select and instead of the * I just put the exact columns

Comment: Awesome yeah I forgot to add the insert when I was doing my testing.